# Upsert in Riak TS

Tags: riak, riak-ts

Is there any way to upsert in RIAK TS, like one can do in Mongodb?

Do I have to check if a key exists and if it does, manually overwrite it? Or can I assume that an insert will overwrite any existing key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Riak TS is geared towards immutable data it is possible to update existing records. INSERT operations will overwrite existing keys. There is no upsert functionality.